# MouseEvents or TouchEvents, any difference in execution speed?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, optimization, air, mouseevent

I'm building an air app which will run on iPads. For the touch interaction I'm using just MouseEvents handlers (MOUSE_DOWN, MOUSE_MOVE, MOUSE_OUT, MOUSE_UP) because my app don't need multitouch, now I'm wondering if there is any difference in execution speed, should I use the equivalent touch events or the mouse events are faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MouseEvent`s will be faster and easier since you don't have to write extra logic to ignore secondary touches.

For performance, the most important thing to do is set `mouseEnabled = false` and `mouseChildren = false` wherever you can.  Otherwise Flash will be checking every `DisplayObject` for mouse events, and dragging your finger across the screen will cause a drop in frame rate.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no performance difference.